# SELECT COUNT sql function in postgres always errors out, non-SETOF

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, count

I have been trying to return an sql count function as an INTEGER in postgres but it always returns the following error `ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`. I have tried the below query and variants of it but it has always resulted in the same failure.

I have also see the `cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GetUser"(
  "@id"            UUID
)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT COUNT("id")
    FROM "users" as u
    WHERE u."id" = "@id"
 );
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: "ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" is thrown if an error happened in a transaction, that caused it's abortion, when you try to execute other commands before doing `ROLLBACK`. Your function looks OK. So I suspect there are errors somewhere before the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It was working now. I believe that the issue was that is was conflicting with another function of the same name. But I also refreshed and restarted everything so I cannot guarantee that is the solution.

It does work now however.